# Subtraction formula which ignores or treats any non-number precedent cell as 0 (to fix #VALUE! error)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to subtract cells, but when one or both of them is blank, or contains text, the subtract formula returns a #VALUE! error.
I am using `=SUM(A1-B1)`.

Can anyone please help with the formula which will treat A1 as 0 (or ignore it)  if it is blank or contains text, and will separately treat B1 as 0 (or ignore it) if it is blank or contains text?

(I don't want to change the precedent cells themselves.)  I can't figure out how to structure IF, AND and ISNUMBER.

[image: Error subtracting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(C38),(C38),0)-IF(ISNUMBER(K38),(K38),0))` seems to do the trick - for fellow sufferers :)

Comment: SUM is not needed in your formula, it would also work without that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter formula :

`=IFERROR(A1+0,0)-IFERROR(B1+0,0)`

`+0` is used to force converting to numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `C1` and copied down:

```
=N(A1)-N(B1)
```

Regards